# Remove addons from tabs in 3d window

Tags: interface, add-on

I made my own tab *SV*, but there are addons that I do not need, *Oscurart Tools* ,*Contour Retopolgy* and *Object Tools*. Why are they not in their own tabs?

green - my panels, red - not mine
[image]

If I activate new addons they appear here in my tab also. How to delete the other addons from my list, or how to move my own on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an addon defines a panel for the toolbar it should add a property called `bl_category` which defines the name of the tab it will be shown in. If this property is not defined then the panel will be shown in every toolbar tab.

Current repository versions of Contours and Oscurart Tools have been updated to have their own tabs. Contours was updated in January and Oscurart Tools in February. The solution for these would be to update them.

```
class CGCOOKIE_OT_retopo_contour_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    '''Retopologize Forms with Contour Strokes'''
    bl_category = "Retopology"
    bl_label = "Contour Retopolgy"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
```

I don't know which addon Object Tools belongs to. To manually fix this edit it's source file by right-clicking on one of it's buttons and select Edit Source. Then add a `bl_category` property to the panel. If this addon is located within the official addons or addons_contrib then you will need to repeat this when you upgrade, if the addon still hasn't been updated. If it is an official addon or from addon_contrib them submit a bug report (include a patch?) to get it updated.

Comment: object tool - tool frm oscurart toolbox